# Making the drawables work according to resolution

Tags: android, android-layout

I made all the drawables for my android app, and it is in xxhdpi folder. How can I make sure that the app will downsize the drawables according to the resolution phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this link
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html for converting your image to the 9 patch images and down load it in .rar format. Extract it and paste into resource folder.by using 9 patch images are chooses according to the resolution of the device..
and if you want to take the icons you can use vector drawable . it will help to reduce your app size and best for all resolution devices.

for taking Vector Drawable 
Right click on Drawable --> New --> Vector Assest .

Comment: I'm using eclipse Juno for developing my app. I wanna know whether, the phone will rescale the image according to its resolution. Or should I make separate pictures for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi?

Comment: Please use Android studio because google is stoping the support or the ec

Comment: Dont worry about it 9 patch images is convert your icon into Differant types of sizes  it gives you the . the Please use Android studio because google is stoping the support or the

Comment: Please use Android studio because google is stoping the support or the Eclipse see this link "http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/06/26/google-officially-ends-support-for-adt-with-eclipse-urges-android-developers-to-migrate-projects-to-android-studio/"    . and for any other query use "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563435/how-to-use-nine-patch-images-correctly"

Comment: Thanks mate. Anyway , it's working right now in playstore. So, yeah, for my future projects I would definitely go for android studio. Is there any par plugins that you recommend for android studio?

Comment: @Nidhin Velayudhan .. if you like you can up vote my answare .. and

Comment: android studio is already very strong tool and containing all the plugin Automatically .

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to scale the drawables manually and put in the right folder (e.g. -mdpi, -ldpi, ...), then the best solution could be use `SVG` format. Read more about this topic [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html).
Another benefit of using SVGs is that your app will use less space on the device.